# SSL Version and Open SSL version are different in ubuntu 14.04 with php version 5.6

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-14.04, openssl, php5, phpinfo

I see the different versions on running this terminal

`echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | php 2>&1 |grep -i ssl`

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
SSL => Yes
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1f
core SSL => supported
extended SSL => supported
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Comment: Please show the complete output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this 
I have pasted it here https://pastebin.com/4F6HTjGr

Comment: Please add this information to the question itself, not to an external site where the information might be eventually lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the versions of two different pieces of PHP.

The first output is for the `curl` module. PHP's `curl` interface uses the `curl` library provided by the OS, which then uses the OpenSSL library it is linked against, in this case `1.0.1f`.

Then, PHP has a direct OpenSSL interface, which is linked against version `1.1.0g`.

If you want `curl` to use a newer OpenSSL version, you need to upgrade your `curl` library, and make sure PHP's `curl` module uses the newer library.

Comment: Ok understood.
I want to my PHP to use OpenSSL of version 1.0.1f, what should I do for that?

Comment: The actual issue I'm facing is I'm trying to use `DSS1` algorithm to sign some data and I want to get that algorithm from the output of `openssl_get_md_methods()`. Bu with this setup the output of this method is https://pastebin.com/9hmP4DtQ But in another setup, I have both the SSL versions same(1.0.1f with php vesion 5.5.9) where the response of that method is https://pastebin.com/TD2p4xDU

Comment: You should actually open another question when the question changes like this. However, according to https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/1132, you can use SHA1 instead of DSS1. This also explains why this change happened. Another option is to find a PHP version that uses OpenSSL 1.0.1f, however it is not recommended to use previous versions of software.